# Excel VBA Do Until Cell.Value = "abc"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count up a number in row i and column 4 with one, starting from i = "REOPEN_FOR_NEW_OFFER" and until the word "COMPLETE" appears in column 4. Then it stops until the next "REOPEN_...." comes.

Is my way I am thinking logical? The debugger says there is an error in the Do Until line.

Thx in advance!

```
Sub Test1()

Dim letzteZeile
letzteZeile = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = letzteZeile To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = "REOPEN_FOR_NEW_OFFER" Then

        Do Until Cells(i, 4).Value = "COMPLETE"
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value + 1
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error? I'm guessing you incremented `i` until you got an invalid cell address (off the bottom of the sheet). I'm not exactly clear on why you're incrementing your loop counter inside a descending loop - that seems like a good way to prevent it from exiting.

Comment: Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

Comment: That would seem to confirm that you're running off the end of the worksheet. Can you include a screenshot or some example of the data you're working with. It's not clear at all from the code what you're intending to do.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Actually row 7149 has also number (column c) 11447895 like until row 7156, it just changed because I ran my VBA once before I added the Do Until. Now, I want to change alle numbers into 11447895 until COMPLETE and from SEND it keeps like it is.

Comment: You seem to be having a logic error: you first go back until a REOPEN. Then you go forward and increment cells until COMPLETE. Now you go back again until REOPEN, but that will be the same REOPEN you found the first time.

Comment: If, on going forward, you do not find a COMPLETE, you will fall off the sheet, as othes noted.

Comment: If it is like find REOPEN_FOR_NEW_OFFER from bottom -> Go down to COMPLETE increment   Col C. then first of all place `Exit For` just above 'End if ' or it will go into never ending loop between that range. It is not giving any error to my trial.

Comment: @AhmedAU I would guess that there is a formula in the Column D, which would let the result change according to the value in Col C. If not, then you are right, never ending loop.

Comment: Ahh I understand my problem now. I'm starting at the buttom of the sheet and go upward in the table. In the IF statement I'm going down again so it stucks as a loop. Thx guys and sorry for my noob behavior, I'm completely new with VBA. How can I just start from the first row and check every row until the end or in another question how can I select the whole sheet?

Comment: @Jochbart . Don't feel sorry ever when coding.. Even _expert of the experts_ made sliiy error. that may lead to something more innovative idea. This give me idea to scientific modelling of YoYo with mass, elasticity and gravitational  force etc.